# Password Reset Script Setup for Delegated Control User Group

Tags: powershell, permissions, active-directory

I am trying to delegate a user group (non-administrators) to handle password reset for an organizational unit. Since I can't install Active Directory Users and Computers on the client computer, I wrote the two following scripts:

Test.ps1:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName DC -FilePath \\DC\SharedFolder\passwordreset.ps1
```

passwordreset.ps1:

```
Function GenerateStrongPassword ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][int]$PasswordLength)
{
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
    $PassComplexCheck = $false
    do {
        $newPassword=[System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword($PasswordLength,1)
        If ( ($newPassword -cmatch "[A-Z\p{Lu}\s]") `
        -and ($newPassword -cmatch "[a-z\p{Ll}\s]") `
        -and ($newPassword -match "[\d]") `
        -and ($newPassword -match "[^\w]")
        )
        {
            $PassComplexCheck=$True
        }
    } While ($PassComplexCheck -eq $false)
    return $newPassword
}

Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$newPassword = GenerateStrongPassword(13)
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $newPassword -Force
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity test -NewPassword $securePassword -Reset
$newPassword
```

It works fine on the administrator account, but it doesn't work on any user of the user group I delegate control to. It complaints about...

```
PS C:\Users\User1\Downloads> powershell -executionpolicy bypass -file test.ps1
[DC] Connecting to remote server DC failed with the following error message : Access is
denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (DC:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionStateBroken
```

I have verified that the user group has the following permission over the organizational unit:

- Reset password
- Read pwdLastSet
- Write pwdLastSet

I also verified that the user group has read and read & execute permission on the shared folder and PowerShell script file. What other permission am I missing to get this to work for a non-administrator user account.

Comment: Do the users have rights to execute powershell sessions remotely on the DC?

Comment: Not just that, but are you running your powershell as admin?

Comment: Honestly it sounds like you need to setup a session configuration for the users to connect to that will automatically load the ActiveDirectory module, then have your Test.ps1 script create a session with the right configuration, and `import-pssession` to bring the AD cmdlets to the local session. Then you can execute the cmdlets you need without having to install the AD module on everybody's computers.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Oh, that might be what I am missing - right to execute powershell sessions remotely. Going to give that a try tomorrow.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I can't run powershell as admin, because I need it to be run by a non-admin user.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician That was exactly what I am missing. I need to add it to BUILTIN\Remote Management Users. Please post your answer, so I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main clue here is this:

```
[DC] Connecting to remote server DC failed with the following error message : Access is denied.
```

It looks like your users do not have permission to create remote PowerShell sessions on the DC. You'll need to grant them rights to execute commands on the DC.

If this is a Domain Controller you may want to consider setting up a session with a session configuration on the DC that they can import into their local session and use the ActiveDirectory cmdlets from there rather than allowing them to execute things on the DC itself. Or perhaps spin up a VM with the AD module installed that they can execute the script on. Most security personnel would frown at giving non-essential users access to execute things on your domain controller.